# Hide dynamic URL directory

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, dynamic, hide

My request looks familiar but there is a trick :)
We have a website that redirects to a daily created folder for the main page content.

```
website.com/static-folder/dd-mmm-yyyy/index.html
```

So, *website.com* goes to the URL above with today's date.

How can we always hide the directories from the URL, and show only the domain name?

```
website.com
```

I know that using *mod_rewrite* does the job, but don't know the code to dynamically change the date folder.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static-folder/dd-mmm-yyyy/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static-folder/dd-mmm-yyyy/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /index.html [L]
```

thanks,

Comment: thank you @CBroe, but this didn't work. I'm getting (500 Internal Server Error error) and I've edited the question above as the folder represents months in 3 letter format (Jan, Dec, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment variables listed in the [description of `RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for that – there you’ll find `TIME_DAY`, `TIME_MON` and `TIME_YEAR`. The first two are of two digit lenght (prefixed with zero when applicable), and the third one is four digits.

You can use them in a `RewriteRule` substitution directly, something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static-folder/{TIME_DAY}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_YEAR}/$1
```

should work for your case.

Not sure though, whether you can use them in your second `RewriteCond` that you already have there as well, on the right-hand side for comparison. But your conditions #3 and #4 should be enough already to stop rewriting here, because once the request has been rewritten to the existing current day’s folder, `!-f` resp. `!-d` should catch that already.

Comment: I'm getting (500 Internal Server Error error) and I've edited the question above as the folder represents months in 3 letter format (Jan, Dec, ...)

Comment: is there a way to save /static-folder/dd-mmm-yyyy/ into a variable and add it to RewriteRule?

Comment: No trivial way that I can think of right now – after all, this would have to happen before rewriting starts. Well, of course you could update your `.htaccess` file daily – but that doesn’t seem to be a very smooth solution … maybe it’d better to tackle this at the point where those daily folders are _created_ already (f.e. by setting a simple symlink to always point to the current folder or something).